# Show input file name in DOM using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to show the input file name in a readonly text box.[image]

[image]

As can be seen this is different from the custom input file of HTML.

So, I tried this.

```
<input type="text" readonly ng-model="name">. 
<input style="display: none" id="upload" type="file" accept=".csv" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChange(this)">
<button type="button" ng-click="clickUpload()">Browse</button>

$scope.fileNameChange = function(e) {
        $scope.name=e.files[0].name
    }
    $scope.clickUpload = function(){
        angular.element('#upload').trigger('click');
    };
```

With this logic, say I first select 'inputFile1.csv', nothing is shown in the textbox.

Then I select another file 'inputFile2.csv', now 'inputFile1.csv' is shown in textbox.

Where am I going wrong? Also, is this the best way to implement this functionality?

Comment: Do a bunch of googling about this. It's a real snafu to access the file input - and for good (security related) reasons. There are some file upload angularJS packages out there might be worth taking a peek at.

Comment: I am getting the filename, i.e. I'm getting it correctly when I log it. It's only when I want to show it in the DOM, that this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" readonly ng-model="name">. 
<input style="display: none" id="upload" type="file" accept=".csv" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChange(this)">
<button type="button" ng-click="clickUpload()">Browse</button>

$scope.fileNameChange = function(e) {
   // let the DOM process before letting angular do its thing
   $timeout(function() {
      $scope.name=e.files[0].name
   });
}
$scope.clickUpload = function(){
   angular.element('#upload').trigger('click');
};
```